# Office Interop (Outlook): SaveSentMessageFolder does not work when using SentOnBehalfOfName / Shared Inbox

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, office365, office-interop

I am using [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook) with PowerShell to automatically send emails using a local Outlook client. My org has restricted other means of automating email (no app passwords for SMTP, cannot use `Mail.Send` with a Microsoft Graph app), so I think this is my best option.

My code looks like this:

```powershell
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
Add-Type -assembly "System.Runtime.Interopservices"

$oClient = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
$oNamespace = $oClient.GetNamespace("MAPI")

$sharedFolder = $oClient.Session.Folders | Where-Object -Property Name -eq -Value "<Shared Mailbox Name>"
$sharedSentFolder = $sharedFolder.Folders | Where-Object -Property Name -eq -Value "Sent Items"

function Send-OutlookEmail {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $OutlookClient,

        # Could pull this every time the function is called but it's probably better
        # to just have a single declaration. Idk.
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $OutlookNamespace,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Recipient,

        [string[]]$CC,

        [string[]]$BCC,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Subject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$HTMLBody,

        [bool]$ReadReceipt = $false,

        [int]$Priority = 1,

        [string]$SendFromAddress,

        $SentMessageFolder
    )

    $email = $OutlookClient.CreateItem(0) # OlItemType.olMailItem

    $rcp = $email.Recipients.Add($Recipient)
    $rcp.Type = 1

    $email.Subject = $Subject
    $email.BodyFormat = 2 # OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
    $email.HTMLBody = $HTMLBody

    $email.ReadReceiptRequested = $ReadReceipt
    $email.Importance = $Priority

    if ($CC) {
        foreach ($cc in $CC) {
            $r = $email.Recipients.Add($cc)
            $r.Type = 2 # CC (OlMailRecipientType.olCC)
        }
    }

    if ($BCC) {
        foreach ($bcc in $BCC) {
            $r = $email.Recipients.Add($bcc)
            $r.Type = 3 # BCC (OlMailRecipientType.olBCC)
        }
    }

    if ($SendFromAddress) {
        $email.SentOnBehalfOfName = $SendFromAddress
    }

    if ($SentMessageFolder -and $OutlookNamespace) {
        $sf = $oNamespace.GetFolderFromID($SentMessageFolder.EntryID, $SentMessageFolder.StoreID)

        $email.SaveSentMessageFolder = $sf
    }

    try {
        # Send the email
        $email.Send()
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error sending email to " $Recipient "!"
    }
}

Send-OutlookEmail `
    -OutlookClient $oClient `
    -OutlookNamespace $oNamespace `
    -SendFromAddress "mysharedmailbox@example.com" `
    -SentMessageFolder $sharedSentFolder `
    -Recipient "me@example.com" `
    -Subject "This is a test email" `
    -HTMLBody "<html><body><p>Hello there.</p></body></html>"
```

My issue is this: even though `$email.SaveSentMessageFolder` is properly set (I have triple-checked this), the "sent" email is always moved to my account's "Sent Items" folder rather than the "Sent Items" folder for `$email.SentOnBehalfOfName`.

When I added some debug prints to this function, I got this output:

```
[DEBUG] pre: \\me@example.com\Sent Items
[DEBUG] post: \\SentOnBehalfOfName Display Name\Sent Items
[DEBUG] just before send: \\SentOnBehalfOfName Display Name\Sent Items
```

But I'm under the impression that I am correctly selecting the folder, and I am not getting any errors when calling the function and sending an email.

Comment: Hello, I guess this is the default behavior with outlook itself. Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Exchange account (whether 365 or On-Prem) then the normal expected behaviour is for the sent email to be saved into the Sent Items folder of the person sending the email, NOT of the mailbox that it was sent as. I wonder if that behaviour is being retained even though you're specifying the specific folder of the other mailbox.

If that is the case, I'd try adjusting the setting on the SentOnBehalfOf mailbox. Annoyingly there's no longer a way to tell it to only save there, but you can get it to save a copy there using the following command in Exchange

`set-mailbox <mailbox name> -MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled $True`

You can read more about the issue here (note, it talks specifically about 365, but the issue also applies to Onprem Exchange). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/user-and-shared-mailboxes/sent-mail-is-not-saved

Additionally, I notice all the references I see to `SaveSentMessageFolder` reference selecting the folder in regards to the folder within main mailbox, not another one (eg the sent on behalf of mailbox), and that it saves a copy of the message after it's being saved to the Sent Items as normal, so that line of your code might simply being ignored.

Finally, there's a discussion of someone doing similar to you (though in VB not PS) here - https://www.slipstick.com/exchange/save-items-shared-mailbox-exchange-server-cmdlet/ - that echos much of what I'd said, but also suggests the same solution, plus showing where the `MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled` can be found within the Exchange UI.